# Bases of orthogonal complements

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $w_1,..,w_n$ is a base of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $S_j$ be subsets of ${1,2,...,n}$. Define $H_j=span\{w_i : i\in S_j\}$. Does there exist a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $H_j^{\perp}=span\{v_i : i\in S_j^{c}\}$?

For example in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I think we can do it using something like a biorthogonal set. But with general $S_j$ and in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I cannot make a proof that works in general.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think that there's a problem with what you've asked. Your last set --- just before the "?" --- should probably contain $v_i$ rather than $w_i$. Also, you'll get more/better answers if you include your own thoughts on the problem (click "edit" just below the question to change/add stuff!). Have you worked through the case when $n = 2$ or $n = 3$? Do you believe that the answer is "yes" or "no" based on those preliminary investigations? How have you thought about approaching the problem (aside from asking someone else to answer it for you)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made an edit to fix the typo and I added some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

**Quite broad hint (but deliberately not a complete answer**

If your question means "regardless of the choice of $S_j$, is there always a solution?", then we might as well take the set of $S_j$ to be the power set of $1, 2, \ldots, n$, since that results in the greatest possible collection of constraints (and any other choice for the $S_j$s results in a subset of this constraint set).

Now for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$ look at $T_k = \{1, 2, \ldots, k-1, k+1, \ldots n\}$, so that the corresponding $H$ will be the span of "all but the $k$th basis vector". The orthogonal complement of this $H$ will be a line, hence be spanned by a single vector, which (up to sign and length, which don't matter) must be chosen as $v_k$.

Now all you have to do is figure out whether these $v_k$ vectors ($k = 1, \ldots, n$) actually satisfy the constraints for every possible subset $S$ of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Thanks. It seems also that if we let $A$ the matrix with columns $w_i$, then if $v_i$ are the columns of $A^{-1}$, they have the desired property.

Comment: Indeed. My description is basically a *construction* of $A^{-1}$, except that I don't worry about the lengths of the columns.